# SQL table join based on minimum time difference

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query that I'm struggling with.  The concept is that there are outgoing messages and then responses to the message.  At times there can be many nearly identical messages with identical responses, with the only differences being the key value and the timestamp.  For each sent message I want the first response message that occurred after the sent message time, which could also be interpreted as the minimum DATEDIFF.

Here is my query

```
SELECT 
    one.event_timestamp as sent_time
    ,two.event_timestamp return_time
    ,one.hdr_key sent_key
    ,two.hdr_key return_key
    ,one.item_number
    ,one.sequence_number sent_seq
    ,two.response_sequence_number return_seq
    ,two.text as responseText
    ,two.message_id
    ,one.city
    ,DATEDIFF(second, one.event_timestamp, two.event_timestamp) as timeDiffSeconds
FROM message one
JOIN response two
    ON one.sequence_number = two.response_sequence_number
    AND one.city=two.city
    AND one.event_timestamp <= two.event_timestamp
WHERE one.event_timestamp BETWEEN @BeginDateTime AND @EndDateTime
AND DATEDIFF(second, one.event_timestamp, two.event_timestamp) < 13
AND two.ack_message_id='Purchase'
```

Example results:
[image]

There can be many messages in the allowed 13 second time frame with just as many responses.  This is making for a lot of errant joins.  I need each sent and response message to only be utilized once at max.  I appreciate any help!

To phrase the questions:

```
JOIN 'Message' with 'Response' based on these conditions
    ON one.sequence_number = two.response_sequence_number
    AND one.city=two.city
    AND one.event_timestamp <= two.event_timestamp
Based on the minimum positive time difference between one.event_timestamp and two.event_timestamp
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: Gordon: It is a SQL Server DB
Desired results: I need each sent and response message to only be utilized once at max.
As to the sample data, I was hoping the provided results would help with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the part that make sure you get only the first response:

```
    SELECT 
        one.event_timestamp as sent_time
        ,two.event_timestamp return_time
        ,one.hdr_key sent_key
        ,two.hdr_key return_key
        ,one.item_number
        ,one.sequence_number sent_seq
        ,two.response_sequence_number return_seq
        ,two.text as responseText
        ,two.message_id
        ,one.city
        ,DATEDIFF(second, one.event_timestamp, two.event_timestamp) as timeDiffSeconds
    FROM message one
    JOIN response two
        ON one.sequence_number = two.response_sequence_number
        AND one.city=two.city
        AND one.event_timestamp <= two.event_timestamp
    WHERE one.event_timestamp BETWEEN @BeginDateTime AND @EndDateTime
    AND DATEDIFF(second, one.event_timestamp, two.event_timestamp) < 13
    AND two.ack_message_id='Purchase'

    AND not exists(select 1 from response tree 
where two.response_sequence_number = tree.response_sequence_number AND tree.city=two.city AND tree.event_timestamp < two.event_timestamp)
```

Comment: Zip, thanks for the response.  I have only been working in SQL for a few months.  Can you explain how this works?

Comment: Konan, your code gave you all you need almost. that only thing I added is some code to exclude all responses except the first one. So my code " give me all the responses found by Konan for which does not exists an answer to the same message that happened before".  Hope it is clear

Comment: I don't believe this is working as expected.  When I add your code to the end of my query I am only getting 2,206 rows afterwards.  I used a group by on the sent_key for my original query and received 7,860 unique key values.  I cross checked with the number of "messages" sent in the time frame and there were 7,884 total "message" entries, so the results from my GROUP BY retained each unique sent_key as expected whereas your addition seemed to drop a lot of the unique sent key joins.